# Android can not create media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-textureview

I have one mp4 video and i try to play my video in TextureView.

I have one problem. In Nexus or HTC one i have no problem but in some Huawei devices i have this message

```
Unable To create Media player
```

this is a my source

```
 private void playVideoAnimation()
{
    textureView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {
            Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

            try {
                Log.e("FILE_NAME", FILE_NAME);
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(FILE_NAME);

                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);

                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                        }
                        mediaPlayer.start();

                    }
                });
                mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {


            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    });

    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            Log.e("FILE_NAME", "Finished");

        }

    });



}
```

as I said I can play my video in Nexus and HTC devices but  yesterday i run my app in Huawei and i have this error message.

How i can check if device can play video?

If anyone knows solution please help me